# Change Linux System Time Relatively

Tags: linux, time

I need a script which will modify the system time by `x` amount of minutes. Something like:

```
#time = 12:56
#x = 2

if time_bool:
  time = time + x
  #time = 12:58
else:
  time = time - x
  #time = 12:54
```

It's apart of some Red Hat testing but may need to be moved to another OS (probably Fedora or CentOS).

Comment: I guess you are aware that *bad things* have been known to happen when time goes backwards on a Unix/Linux system.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on *bad things*? My Linux systems experience is limited! My goal is to test a solution which involves multiple Linux boxes. One of the scripts involves randomly changing the time to see how it reacts.

Comment: Bad things: Processes that expect 12:03 to happen after 12:00, Cron jobs that run twice, programs that find something they just did has already happened in the future, children finding their parents died before they were born, lions lying down with sheep, the awakening of the old ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do

```
if $time_bool; then
    date --set="+${x} minutes"
else
    date --set="-${x} minutes"
fi
```

The date string syntax in `GNU date` is quite loose and permits many things.

Tested on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way might be:

```
date --set=@$(( $(date +%s) + 120 ))
```

(Untested)

But I can't guarentee this'll work between OS' since `date +%s` is an extension.

The script tries to get the current date UTC, convert this into seconds from the epoch, add 120 seconds, then set the date from Unix epoch seconds.

Comment: You can't nest backticks that way. Use `$( )` instead, and `$(( ))` for the calculation. Note that `--set` is a GNU extension too, and it accepts the same formats as `-d`, so `--set=@12345` should work directly.

Comment: Good edit, thanks for that. Why is it necessary to use double brackets for the calculation?

Comment: Because `$(` and `$((` are two different operators. `$(` runs a process, `$((` performs calculations. The operator itself is needed because `date` does not perform calculations itself if you give it a `@timestamp`.